# Bootstrap failing with Drush 9.1.0

Tags: 8, drush, installation

I had Drush 9 working before it got upgraded to 9.1.0 and am a little bit at my wits end why Bootstrap is failing and why I get "Bootstrap failed" or "! [NOTE] Drupal root not found. Pass --root or a @siteAlias in order to see Drupal-specific commands."

- My build directory is separate from my vendor directory. (shorthanded below to `[build]` and `[composer]`)
- There are a couple of debugged commands below, one trying to use an alias, and one just using the help command.
- There are a couple extra alias paths (the last two) which are not valid and I can't figure out where they come from (they are not in my `drush.yml` anywhere), but my alias file is found... `@default.dev` does seem to work.
- adding `-r` or `-uri` (or using that in place of the alias) does not make any difference... I still get the Bootstrap failed.

What has changed from earlier versions of Drush 9, or what am I doing incorrectly here? There was similar things with Drush 8 at some point, but none of the solutions that I saw in there worked, and I didn't see anything specific to Drush 9.

```
[794e@794elmp01 htdocs]$ drush @default.dev cr -d
 [preflight] Config paths: /../.drush/drush.yml,/var/..[composer]/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
 [preflight] Alias paths: /../.drush/sites,/var/..[build]/sites,/var/..[build]/drush/sites,/var/..[composer]/drush/sites
 [preflight] Commandfile search paths: /var/../vendor/drush/drush/src
 [bootstrap] Bootstrap to site [0.2 sec, 10.19 MB]
  [Exception]
  Bootstrap failed.
Exception trace:
 () at /var/..[composer]/vendor/drush/drush/src/Boot/BootstrapHook.php:31
 Drush\Boot\BootstrapHook->initialize() at /var/..[composer]/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:34
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->callInitializeHook() at /var/..[composer]/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:27
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->initialize() at /var/..[composer]/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:117
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->initializeHook() at /var/..[composer]/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php:391
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->initialize() at /var/..[composer]/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:229
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/..[composer]/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:859
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/..[composer]/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:206
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/..[composer]/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:125
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/..[composer]/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:112
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at /var/..[composer]/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:41
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /var/..[composer]/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:64
 require() at /var/..[composer]/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4
```

```
drush list -d
 [preflight] Config paths: /home/../.drush/drush.yml,/var/..[composer]/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
 [preflight] Alias paths: /home/../.drush/sites,/var/..[build]/sites,/var/..[build]/drush/sites,/var/..[composer]/drush/sites
 [preflight] Commandfile search paths: /var/..[composer]/vendor/drush/drush/src
 [bootstrap] Bootstrap to max [0.22 sec, 10.14 MB]
 [debug] Trying to bootstrap as far as we can [0.22 sec, 10.15 MB]
Drush Commandline Tool 9.1.0
! [NOTE] Drupal root not found. Pass --root or a @siteAlias in order to see Drupal-specific commands.
```

Also, additional info: this is the site reference in the `default.site.yml`:

```
dev:
  root: /var/..[build]/htdocs
  uri: http://dev.our.internal.url.com
```

I verified that the root and URI were correct, and that the URI was accessible from the server (it is not a public URI).

EDIT: Adding Drush Status (per request)

```
 drush status -d
 [preflight] Config paths: /home/../.drush/drush.yml,/var/[composer]/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
 [preflight] Alias paths: /home/../.drush/sites,/var/[build]/sites,/var/[build]/sites,/var/[composer]/drush/sites
 [preflight] Commandfile search paths: /var/[composer[/vendor/drush/drush/src
 [bootstrap] Bootstrap to max [0.19 sec, 10.14 MB]
 [debug] Trying to bootstrap as far as we can [0.19 sec, 10.15 MB]
 PHP binary    : /usr/bin/php
 PHP config    : /etc/php.ini
 PHP OS        : Linux
 Drush script  : /var/[composer]/vendor/bin/drush
 Drush version : 9.1.0
 Drush temp    : /tmp
 Drush configs : /home/../.drush/drush.yml
                 /var/[composer]/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
```

Comment: So what does `drush status` give you? Have you tried running Drush from different directories - project root, site root and so on. Which OS?

Comment: Added the drush status to the question... I get the same values in the build folder and in the composer folder, in the sites/default folder (and in other folders in my multi-site), and in the root of the sites folder 

Running on CentOS Linux

Comment: So I just backed out to Drush 9.0.0-beta8 and things are working again. Although it's no longer finding the aliases for some reason. I can only refer to sites with --uri and -root (or if I am in the specific directory)

Comment: I walked through the releases and things changed with Drush 9.0.0-rc2

Comment: Nice job on tracking down when the problem was introduced. I think you have to test the newly released 9.2.0 version too. If that also doesn't work, I think you have to reopen the Github issue you created. I wonder: Have you installed a site-local Drush as expected by Drush 9 - ref http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ It's hard to tell from your info.

Comment: It turns out the base issue is that there is no composer.json in my Drupal build, which I don't understand why there wouldn't be. 

The DrupalFinder code which establishes where your drupal directory. Expects one... in earlier versions of Drush 9 -- the code was inadvertently identifying a composer.json until there was an update to how Drush code resolved paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled (and fell) upon the same issue today.

Following your work (missing composer.json at drupal's docroot), I was able to get over this problem, by making sure scaffolding was in place (inside drupal-project's composer.json).
i.e.:

```
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@drupal-scaffold",
        "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@drupal-scaffold",
        "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
    ]
```

This may be quite obvious but got drush 9.2.1 working fine for me.

Good luck

Comment: Sadly, this does not work my particular situation, so likely going back to drawing board. I will mark this as answered, in case people have a situation like yours.

Comment: Too bad. So the scaffolded files are present and you still get the error I guess?

Comment: yep, still not bootstrapping at all.

Answer (score 6):

I has this issue and found this to work:

```
rm -Rf vendor/drush
composer install
```

Credit: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/2959#issuecomment-332054773

This deletes drush and uses the composer.lock file to re-instate drush from the version specified there.

Version of drush is 9.5.2 on my setup (after running above command at time of writing).

Comment: Thanks for putting in this @therobyouknow I've not seen this problem in ages, hopefully this might help someone in the future.

Comment: +1 @Adrained you're welcome!

Comment: This worked for me. Think some of the permissions had changed for this directory and reinstalling corrected that

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when upgrading from drush 8 to drush 9.

Drush was failing to find the settings files on the server I deployed to.

When creating the artifact for deployment, I had previously stripped out unnecessary files, including `__PROJECT_ROOT__/composer.json`.

It turns out, when I made sure `__PROJECT_ROOT__/composer.json` was included on the server, drush 9 found the settings files, and the database connection.

Comment: Thanks for putting this solution in @mcaleaa, looks like there are multiple solutions. Hopefully it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen when `composer.json` is in place, but the additional pieces that move `drupal/core` from `vendor` into the web root are not fully in place.

I ran into this when updating a library that was using the old `drupal/drupal` package to the now standard `drupal/core-recommended`.

Even after adding this to `composer.json` I was still seeing the bootstrap error.

```
    "installer-paths": {
      "web/core": [
        "type:drupal-core"
      ]
    },
    "drupal-scaffold": {
      "locations": {
        "web-root": "web/"
      }
    }
```

The key missing piece was to also add the package `composer/installers` so that Drupal core was moved after downloading:

```
...
"require": {
  ...
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.1",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.1",
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this solution in @jhedtrsom, looks like there are multiple solutions! Hopefully it might help someone in the future.