# Bootstrap failed

Tags: 8, drush

I have Drupal 8.8.1 and Drush 10.1.1, both installed with Composer.

I'm running the following to update my site DB:

```
$ drush updb

In BootstrapHook.php line 32:

  Bootstrap failed. Run your command with -vvv for more information.
```

As it suggests I run with the `-vvv` flag to get more information:

```
$ drush updb -vvv
Begin redispatch via drush_invoke_process().                                                                               [notice]
Calling proc_open(env COLUMNS=131 /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/drush/drush/drush  --root=/var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1 --verbose  updatedb 2>&1);

In BootstrapHook.php line 32:

  [Exception]                                                         
  Bootstrap failed. Run your command with -vvv for more information.  


Exception trace:
  at /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/drush/drush/src/Boot/BootstrapHook.php:32
 Drush\Boot\BootstrapHook->initialize() at /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:34
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->callInitializeHook() at /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:27
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->initialize() at /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:145
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->initializeHook() at /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php:289
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->initialize() at /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:221
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1000
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:118
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:49
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:72
 require() at /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4

$ drush status
 Drupal version : 8.8.1                                                     
 Site URI       : http://default                                            
 PHP binary     : /opt/remi/php72/root/usr/bin/php                          
 PHP config     : /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.ini                               
 PHP OS         : Linux                                                     
 Drush script   : /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/drush/drush/drush     
 Drush version  : 10.1.1                                                    
 Drush temp     : /tmp                                                      
 Drush configs  : /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml 
 Drupal root    : /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.1                              
 Site path      : sites/default
```

Can anyone advise on how to resolve this?

Comment: it seems as though drush can't connect to the database, are you running inside the drupal installation root folder ? Check that the database connectivity is OK.

Comment: Cheers @GiorgosK, I was running it from the directory containing my settings.php file, which in previous versions would run for that site, but doesn't seem to any more.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256526/bootstrap-failing-with-drush-9-1-0/293035#293035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the "status" message, which shows the site path is *sites/default*. In previous versions of Drush, I was able to just change the current directory to the directory containing the settings.php file and Drush would detect the site. Drush 9/10 seems to require I specify it.

Running `drush updb --uri=http:example.com` from the *DRUPAL_ROOT/web* directory worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Delete drush from vendor directory

Go to DRUPAL_ROOT:

```
rm -Rf vendor/drush # in case of Linux system

composer install # Will reinstall requisite drush verion from composer.lock file
```

It worked for me as well as building again detects the site_path to connect database properly

can refer as well  [Bootstrap failing with Drush 9.1.0](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256526/bootstrap-failing-with-drush-9-1-0)

Comment: This solution helped me, the only difference is that I had to make a : `rm -Rf vendor/` instead of just deleting drush

Comment: Man you just saved my life, this totally worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

I have the error while deploying to server

```
In BootstrapHook.php line 32:
                                                                     
Bootstrap failed. Run your command with -vvv for more information.
```

After run `drush -vvv` I saw an error connected with wrong credentials to DB.

So it can be caused also by **wrong credentials/.env file.**